# How to resolve error on Flutter Run - Could not find com.google.firebase:

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Trying to run my flutter program on an android device, not sure how to resolve this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-module-support:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Here is my `android\build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here are the `dependencies` from `android\app\build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-module-support'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin'
}
```

As you can see, there are other `dependencies` that work fine (I removed most of them, but left `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'` in as an example that some work), so I'm not sure what is causing the issue as some seem to work while others don't.

Any help and advice given is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the instructions in Firebase console? they will tell you exactly what to do. I don't remember that I had to add that much packages in the dependencies

Comment: I did try that. I also didn't add these dependencies manually, it was done automatically by `flutter pub get`

Comment: add the content of pubspec.yaml to the question please